Carmichael Theorem (Euler's Generalisation) combinatorial proof.
How can one prove Carmichael Theorem by some combinatorial or geometrical argument.

What exactly are you calling Carmichael's Theorem?  What proofs do you know and what do you find lacking in them?  What have you tried to design a proof of the type you prefer?  What "geometric" proofs in elementary number theory are you thinking of?

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.
